# how to get all value mysql sum and subtract in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I created an API for an accounting application. I have income and spending in one column. How can I sum all the income and spending and subtract?

**This my code:**

```
private function list_recap() {

    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET") {
        $this->response('', 406);
    }

    $year  = $this->_request['year'];
    $month = $this->_request['month'];

    $sqlPlus = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(nominal) 
            FROM lap_keuangan 
                WHERE YEAR(tanggal) = '$year' 
                AND MONTH(tanggal) = '$month' 
           AND kategori = 1");

    $sqlMin  = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(nominal) 
            FROM lap_keuangan 
                WHERE YEAR(tanggal) = '$year' 
                AND MONTH(tanggal) = '$month' 
                AND kategori = -1");


    $result = array();
    while($rowPlus = $sqlPlus->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $plus = $result[] = $rowPlus;
    }

    while($rowMin = $sqlMin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $minus = $result[] = $rowMin;
    }

    $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE-THEN-ELSE` construction, try to execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN kategori = 1 THEN nominal ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN kategori = -1 THEN nominal ELSE 0 END)
FROM lap_keuangan
WHERE
    YEAR(tanggal) = '$year'
    AND MONTH(tanggal) = '$month'
    AND kategori = 1
```

PS:

Your code is vulnerable for SQL Injection attacks. You MUST NOT pass SQL query parameters using strings concatenation. Use `PDO` instead and bind arguments.

Comment: thanks ivan, I'm appreciation your answer and recomendation.

Comment: @nummajaz you are welcome! It looks like Spencer’s answer is more detailed and helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Use one SELECT statement to retrieve the "plus", "minus" and "total". We can use conditional aggregation.  Given a condition in the WHERE clause that guarantees us that `kategori` will have a value of either 1 or -1, we can multiply `nominal` by that, and total that up with SUM.

While we're at it, we should clean up the SQL Injection vulnerability. We *never* want to include potentially unsafe values in SQL text.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

We either properly escape the values before they are included, or we use prepared statement with bind placeholders. (It's not that hard; and there's no valid excuse not to do one or the other.)

For performance, we prefer to have conditions on *bare* columns, rather than wrapping columns in expressions. If `tanggal` is DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype, we can specify condition on that column as a range of values. (This allows MySQL to make use of a range scan operation if a suitable index is available, rather than evaluating expressions on *every* row in the table.)

I'd probably convert the `$year` and `$month` values into a yyyy-mm-01 formatted string, and then pass that date string into the query. But we can pass the $year and $month values into the query, and have MySQL convert that to a date for us.

Something like this:

```
# static SQL text (no variable interpolation) mitigates SQL Injection 
$sql = 
"SELECT SUM( k.nominal * IF(k.kategori=  1 ,1,0) )  AS kat_plus
      , SUM( k.nominal * IF(k.kategori= -1 ,1,0) )  AS kat_minus 
      , SUM( k.nominal * k.kategori              )  AS kat_total
   FROM lap_keuangan k 
  WHERE k.tanggal >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( ? ,'-', ? ,'-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
    AND k.tanggal <  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( ? ,'-', ? ,'-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    AND k.kategori IN (-1,1)";

# prepare
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
```

either use `bindValue` to supply values for each bind placeholder and execute

```
# execute
$sth->bindValue(1, $year    ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(2, $month   ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(3, $year    ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(4, $month   ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

or with positional binds, we can skip the bindValue and just pass an array to execute:

```
# execute
$sth->execute(array($year,$month,$year,$month));
```

then fetch the row, and access the array members

```
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$kat_plus  = $row['kat_plus'];
$kat_minus = $row['kat_minus'];
$kat_total = $row['kat_total'];
```

---

If PDO isn't/hasn't been configured to throw exceptions i.e.

```
$this->$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

then add checks for success/failure of each PDO function call (prepare, execute, fetch) and handle the errors in the code.